# Bilinear map + commitment

Tags: pairings, commitments

Let $\mathbb{G}_1,\mathbb{G}_2,\mathbb{G}_T$ be yclic group of the same order and $ e: \mathbb{G}_1 \times \mathbb{G}_2\rightarrow \mathbb{G}_T$, such that $u\in \mathbb{G}_1, g \in \mathbb{G}_2, a,b,r \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Question 1: is the following equation correct? Is there any situation under which it might be correct? If not why?

$e(u^a,\frac {u^b}{u^a} g)=e(u^b,g)$

---

Scenario: assume we have two parties: $A$ and $B$, where $A$ has two messages $m, m'$ and $B$ has a message $m$. $A$ commitments to a message $m$ as: $(r.u^m)^a$, and B commitments the same message as $(r.u^m)^b$. They send their commitments to a server. It's clear that if $A$ gives $g^{\frac{1}{a}}$ to $B$, $B$ can compute $w=g^{\frac {b}{a}}$, and send it to the server to let the server check whether two messages $m$ for different parties are equal: $e((r.u^m)^a,g^{\frac {b}{a}})=e((r.u^m)^b,g)$

Question 2: Given $g^{\frac{1}{a}}$ can B generate $w'$  to convince the server that it has commited to $m'$ rather than $m$?

All operation are $\bmod p$ where $p$ is a large prime number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define $u$ as element of $G_1$, then you can't just use it in $G_2$ (in the first equation), like you did in your equation. Besides, you missed to state, if $u$ and $g$ are generators of those groups. The following holds:

$$e(u^a,g^{\frac{b}{a}}) = e(u,g)^b = e(u^b,g)$$

Anyway, you didn't do that in the actual question, where I don't really see the connection to your construction. Btw, how do A and B know that they are using the same value $r$? And then: How can the server relate anything $B$ sends to $m'$, if the server has no knowledge of $m'$ or a commitment to $m'$? So no, he can't. Because $m'$ is not used in your construction at all.

The question now is: What is your actual goal? Should the server just be able to make sure, A and B committed to the same value? And A and B have to interact to generate the witness for that? You don't need pairings for that.

*edit:* Maybe even Alice could cheat in the system, by not sending $g^a$ to Bob, but something else. What happens then? Well, if the server check returns true, the "commited" messages are not equal. Too many things that can go wrong, especially with that $r$, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you give me a clue what you mean by " the commited messages are not equal ", please.

Comment: Why would the server change anything? From what you describe, A and B are the ones committing values, and the server is the one verifying that the commitment matches to the value (which is revealed later - if we are still talking about commitment schemes). About the interaction part: I can't give an concrete example, but Alice could send something else other than $g^{1/a}$, and then the pairing equation would be true for messages, where the commitments of A and B are not equal. In order to do that, Alice would know what B was going to commit, and adapt accordingly.

Comment: you are absolutely right. In "my scenario" $A$ is semi_honest, but $B$  is malicious, in the sense that given $g^a$  it may try to modify it and fool the server that it has some other message than what it has already commited to (e.g. $m'$) . Why does it matter? Becasue it may guess that $m'$ is in A's outsourced values and try to get confirmation from the server. This is the "main" reason that the above so called protocol is designed. So the server can detect it if $B$ asks something beyond its outsouced commited values.

Comment: We also have $g^{a}$ that is given to $B$ by $A$. If $B$ modifies it honestly (i.e. it generates $g^{\frac{b}{a}}$) , it could give a mapping from its own outsouced commited value to $A$'s. I need to mention that in the comment (not in the question) I mistakenly used $g^{\frac{1}{a}}$ instead of $g^a$.

Comment: Thus after some computation $B$ gets access to $m$. It sends $(r.u^m)^b$ and $g^{\frac{a}{b}}$ to the server. The server first checks whether $B$ has commited to this value then it uses $g^{\frac{a}{b}}$ to map $B$'s commited value to $A$. And this ensures it that $m$ belongs to both $A$ and $B$ outsourced values.

Comment: Well yes, but how does that help anything. A central question, which is still not clear: Who commits to what, and what are the commitment properties? Binding and hiding properties are what matters for commitments, and you don't mention the revealing either: Who should be convinced, that A and B commited to their messages prior to the unveiling phase?

Comment: In fact here the commited value (e.g. $(r.u^m)^b$ ) is used as a verification tag. So when $B$ gets access to $m$ (after computation) it wants to check whether: 1- it belongs to its original values, that are outsourced and commited. 2- it belongs to $A$'s original outsourced values. However, it should not be able to check $A$'s values for whatever it has not commited. If it does, the server should detect it.